# Can I install Ubuntu in dual boot mode on a disk that has GPT partition style?

Tags: dual-boot, gpt, mbr

Now I am on **Windows 10** but I want to use Ubuntu in dual boot mode. I have a disk named "Disk 0" and it's partition style is **GPT**. Can I do dual boot even if my disk partition style is not in **MBR** mode? Please help me brothers.

Comment: Yes, GPT is very fine.

Comment: MBR is kind of frowned upon these days anyways, due to it being an old and less flexible standard. GPT is preferred.

Comment: See also:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  UEFI recommends gpt, Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot. Ubuntu will work with MBR, but really should not use MBR with UEFI as that often breaks a old Windows BIOS type install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: No, I am not actually asked this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Make certain to defrag then use the disk management to free up space for new partitions. If you want swap then make a tiny about 8gb or leave it out entirely if SSD. It causes too much wear and the OSs like Ubuntu will detect and create a virtual disk for you for its use if necessary. The rest of the free space would be used for the OS install. You need to check your machine is set to boot only EFI by making sure the CSM compatibility is turned off in your firmware. Good luck on the install.